# Aerospike udf lua stream skip filter if condition met

Tags: lua, aggregation, udf, aerospike

Situation:

I have complex bins in aerospike like:
object_id,status,create_time,end_at_time,status_client,assigned_to_id,created_by_id,is_s_provider,is_s_client,start_at_time,_id,end_time

And I need to do aggregation on any of bins field. 
In sql format it should look something like:

```
select count(*) from table where status=13 and where is_s_provider=True;
```

after some research I have made lua module which looks like:

```
function count(stream,created_by,status,status_client,obj,client,provider,assigned_to,create_time,end_time,start_at_time,end_at_time)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    local created_by_f = created_by_filter(created_by)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    local status_f = status_filter(status)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    local status_client_f = status_client_filter(status_client)                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    local obj_f = ojb_filter(obj)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    local client_f = client_filter(client)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    local provider_f = provider_filter(provider)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    local assigned_to_f = assigned_to_filter(assigned_to)
    local create_time_f= create_time_filter(create_time)
    local end_time_f = end_time_filter(end_time)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    local start_at_time_f = start_at_time_filter(start_at_time)
    local end_at_time_f = end_at_time_filter(end_at_time)

    function mapper(rec)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    local function reducer(v1, v2)
        return v1 + v2
    end
    return stream : filter(created_by_f): filter(status_f): filter(status_client_f) : filter(obj_f): filter(client_f): filter(provider_f): filter(assigned_to_f): filter(create_time_f):filter(end_time_f): filter(start_at_time_f): filter(end_at_time_f): map(mapper) : reduce(reducer)
end
```

end filters (I have 11 of them) looks like:

```
....
local function status_client_filter(status_client)
    local key = string.sub(status_client, 1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    local data = string.sub(status_client,2)  
    return function(record)
        if status_client == '*' then
            return true
        elseif key == '!' then  
            if record['status_client'] ~= tonumber(data) then
                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        elseif key == '=' then
            if record['status_client'] == tonumber(data) then
                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
....
```

indexes have been created and in aql to check if it works I run:

```
aql> aggregate count.count('*','*','=13','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*') on test.demo 
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
| 895   |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.219 secs)

aql>
```

all works fine, I get what I want, except one big issue, 0.219 seconds is a lot.

Question:

is there any way to skip filter if condition is met, for example if I pass to filter function status_client_filter('*') then stream filter function should not run through all records, but pass them as it came from stream function before. it should increase performance a lot.
Or is another way do to dynamic filtering? Or another architecture for complex aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

Your application can help here. Filter stage is not mandatory. So, you can have one more high level lua function without the filter stage. Your application can detect if the filter is a `*` and call the filter-less lua function. Moreover, it's better to use a scan based aggregation than a secondary index based one if there are no `where` clauses at all. Scan is much faster than secondary index query.

Answer (score 0):

As of [release 3.12](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/whats-new-aerospike-3-12/) you would do the filtering ahead of calling the UDF using [predicate filtering](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html). This is currently available in the clients for [Java](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html), [C](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/c/d9/d10/as__predexp_8h_source.html), [C#](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/csharp/html/T_Aerospike_Client_PredExp.htm) [Go](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/predexp.go) and others.

This would allow for a lighter, faster UDF that relies on pre-filtering done by the predicate expression.